# Using Node fs module results in error "require is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, fs

I'm attempting to use webpack to bundle up some code. Everything seems to work until I try to use the fs module or a module that has fs as a dependency. I get `ReferenceError: require is not defined`. Here is my webpack config:

```
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");

module.exports = {
    target: "node",
    mode: "development",
    externals: [nodeExternals({ whitelist: [ "lodash", "path" ] })]
};
```

Any thoughts on why I get this error when using `require("fs")` or use a module that has fs as a dependency?

**EDIT**

<s>With the above config I get `require is not defined` when using crypto.</s>

I have remove the dependancy on crypto. We used a unique ID generator that used crypto. I replaced it with a JavaScript module but now I have the above config and still getting require not defined, this time when using path.

Comment: I never did this, but, maybe require('') can goes without quotes.

Comment: fs does not exist on the web envieronment.

Comment: If I switch it to `target: "node"` I get the same problem but with the crypto module.

Comment: try `target: node` and `externals: ['crypto', 'fs']`

Comment: @PlayMa256 changing it to use `externals: ['crypto', 'fs']` seems to have worked but now I'm getting the same error for another module. I'll keep going and see where this leads me.

Comment: When I have `externals: ["crypto", "fs", "cluster"]` I get an error `cluster is not defined`. Any ideas on what might cause that?

Comment: Have you tried to use webpack-node-externals instead of whitelisting everything?

Comment: If I do `externals: [nodeExternals()]` with `const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");` at the top of the file I'm back to require is not defined when using crypto.

Comment: Maybe try `global.require`